# delete a line if a condition occurs using awk or sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

just need your help with this one. i want to delete a line if this format occurs using either awk or sed:

```
BSC+number     BSC+number
```

For example:

```
BSC112         BSC112
core           tag
red            blue
BSC113         BSC114
flu            joke
```

output should be:

```
core           tag
red            blue 
flu            joke
```

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do this with grep:

```
grep -v 'BSC[0-9]\+[[:space:]]\+BSC[0-9]\+' infile
```

Output:

```
core           tag
red            blue 
flu            joke
```

Comment: Thanks man! you might not use sed or awk, but this answers my question. thanks!

Comment: `[[:space:]]\+` would account for tabs as well as spaces.

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
$ sed '/^BSC[0-9]\+\s\+BSC[0-9]\+$/d' file 
core           tag
red            blue 
flu            joke
```

You can use the `-i` option with `sed` to store the changes back to the file:

```
$ sed -i '/^BSC[0-9]\+\s\+BSC[0-9]\+$/d' file
```

Comment: That will also delete `BSCBSC`. You can change `*` to `\+` or `\{1,\}` to change that.

Comment: what is the expansion of `\+\s\+`? I tried `BSC[0-9]* [ ]*BSC[0-9]*` this also seems to work fine

Comment: hi man. thank you for answering. really appreciate it. but after trying your command. it deleted all the text.

Comment: Not possible, the regexp used is the same as @Thor's apart from `\s` for whitespace instead of a literal space and mine is anchored to match whole lines. Either they both don't work, they both do, or you did something different. See http://ideone.com/Vqs0Iu

Comment: I will test this again. I might have done something wrong. again thanks for your time answering this:)

Comment: @abasu the difference between `+` and `*` is `+` means one or more where as `*` means zero or more. The `+` quantifier is part of the extended regexp class so needs to be escaped or the appropriate option used (with GNU sed it's `-r`). `\s` is shorthand for whitespace, tabs, spaces ect.

Comment: okk, thanks for explaining, i need to look into `extended regexp`

Comment: @jonas not all seds support EREs (even with escapes) and not all seds support \s as a shorthand for spaces so maybe one of those is why it's not working for you. The portable way that will work in all seds is `sed -i '/^BSC[0-9][0-9]*[ \t][ \t]*BSC[0-9][0-9]*$/d' file` so try that and if that doesn't work it's something you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

another way:

```
perl -lne 'print unless(/BSC\d+\s+BSC\d+/)' your_file
```

test:

```
> cat temp
BSC112         BSC112
core           tag
red            blue
BSC113         BSC114
flu            joke
> perl -lne 'print unless(/BSC\d+\s+BSC\d+/)' temp
core           tag
red            blue
flu            joke
```

Answer (score 0):

awk '!/BSC/{print}' input > output

Comment: Your solution do not completely answer the question that requires BSC+number twice in a line. More SO answers are supposed to be an help to the community and should include some explanations. Could you update your answer to fit SO standards?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Code only" answers are frowned upon, especially in situations where a number of answers exist and one of those has been selected by the question's poster. Please improve your post by adding an explanation on what your code does and/or why your answer is better than those already posted.